# SSIS Switching Logins on failed connection

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a `SSIS package` that needs to connect to an off-site SQL Server instance.  There are times when `Windows Authentication` is not working properly but `SQL authentication` can be used as a back up.  I want to have an `Execute SQL Task` attempt to use `Windows login` and if that fails, use a constraint to move on to another `Execute SQL Task` using `SQL authentication` and continue executing the package.

[image: OP's image]

When I run this, it fails and stops the package.  The Windows Test is just a simple query "SELECT 1 ConnectionStatus FROM MyTable" so as long as it can connect, the package continues.  I have a Failure constraint the redirects flow to the SQL Test but it doesn't get there.  I even set ForceExecutionValue to True and ForcedExecutionValue to False.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the values for "FailParentOnError" and "FailPackageOnError" on the ExecuteSQL tasks?   And do you have any OnError event handler?

Comment: Tab, the ForcedExecutionValue = False, ForcedExecutionValueType = Boolean and ForceExecutionValue = True.  I have not added any Event handlers to this package.  Still in testing phase of the process.  Also, any idea if the Connection Strings are set for all Task at start up so that I cannout change them during runtime?

Comment: Why are you telling me about ForcedExecutionValue?   Please read my first comment again.

Comment: Man, sorry about that.  Both are set to False.

Comment: It appears I have an answer.  [link](https://gqbi.wordpress.com/2013/06/27/ssis-stopping-an-error-from-propagating-to-its-parent-enabling-an-ssis-package-to-continue-when-an-error-happens/)  Add Error Handler and then set System:Propagate variable to False.  Thanks Tab for your responses.

Comment: Scott, you should post your resolution as an answer, and then click the checkmark next to the answer to close the question, so that your solution might help other people in the future.